# Tab/Indent Error in Python Command Prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python & taking a course where teacher provided a code snippet to work on. The provided snippet is giving me a TabError as below, but I cannot seem to figure out why. I was hoping someone here could point out the issue.

Error Received:
[Error Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o4zC.png)

Code where error occurs (Updated to have code lines instead of screen shot):

```
def filterResultsAcc(self, qcoverage=0.6, scoverage=0.6, evalue=0.01, best_taxon=False):
    results = []
    hits_by_taxon = {}
    for(qstart,qend,sacc,staxid,slen,sstart,send,evalu) in self.blasthits:
        qcov = ((qend-qstart) + 1.0) / float(self.querylen)
        scov = ((send-sstart) + 1.0 / float(slen)
        if qcov >= qcoverage and scov >= scoverage and evalu <= evalue:
            if best_taxon:
                if staxid in hits_by_taxon.keys():
                    (sid,e,qc,sc) = hits_by_taxon[staxid]
                    if evalu < e:
                        hits_by_taxon[staxid] = (sacc,evalu,qcov,scov)
                    elif evalu == e:
                        if qcov > qc:
                            hits_by_taxon[staxid] = (sacc,evalu,qcov,scov)
                        elif qvoc == qc:
                            if scov > sc:
                                hits_by_taxon[staxid] = (sacc,evalu,qcov,scov)
                else:
                    hits_by_taxon[staxid] = (sacc,evalu,qcov,scov)
            else:
                results.append(sacc)
        if best_taxon:
            for taxid in hits_by_taxon.keys():
                (sac,e,qc,sc) = hits_by_taxon[taxid]
                results.append(sacc)
                results.sort()
    return results
```

Comment: Instead of code image you to add actual code in the question It is easy for us to help you

Comment: Had to retype it all by hand, but I've got the code in the post now. Please no down votes

Comment: The code that you now show has in error in line 6--there is a missing right parenthesis. You probably meant to place one after the `1.0`, as in the previous line. But you really should not have retyped your code. You should have copy-and-pasted it from your editor into this web page. We then could have found your errant tab. I have found multiple wrong tabs in that way. But the code you typed uses both tabs and spaces for indentation (I think you used all tabs, this page added some spaces). Don't use tabs in Python! Have your editor replace all tabs with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows that you've mixed `tab` and spaces, just as it says.

If your editor supports it – turn something like "show unprintable characters" to see what your whitespaces really is.

Another way is to select all code, usually editors will distinguish between spaces and tabs.

Comment: So I was able to find that at the beginning of the line in question, they had put spaces instead of tabs. However, now it is returning a syntax error for the command "results.sort()".  Follow-up thoughts on that by chance? I know the sort() method doesn't require any parameters, so I'm a bit dumbfounded on this.

Comment: @ComputerFailure: You *really* need to show your current code as text and the complete traceback for the error. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That is what I attempted to do first (posting the code as text); however, the UNIX command prompt we are working in does not allow me to do this reliably. I really do apologize for the shoddy information I could provide, but it's the best I can work with so far.

Comment: Had to retype it all by hand, but I've got the code in the post now. Please no down votes.